# Tomcat doesn't update until I restarted Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

i have problem with tomcat. when i change something in my xhtml file, tomcat can not show the changes. it shows the page before changing. i restart the tomcat,i clean tomcat work directory, right click on server and select clean, but  i have to restart the eclipse to see the result. i search in google but i could not find which setting i should do in tomcat to solve the problem.in publish tab i selected "automatically publish when resource changes" .
 please help me. i have to restart eclipse for each changing.

Comment: Stop using Tomcat and start working with a real Application Server like JBoss or GlassFish, you won't have to restart the server neither the IDE to update your changes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So if a tire is flat on your car, you recommend buying a 18-wheeler truck instead?  This is a configuration problem, not a web server problem.

Comment: Tomcat is as 'real' as the other servers, it is more lightweight and easier to use and if all you need is a couple of web pages, or a web service, it is a good choice as any.

Comment: @ftom2 Tomcat is a servlet container,it is not a lightweight Web Application Server (e.g. EJB is part of Java EE, and you can't use EJB by default on Tomcat), but that discussion will be off-topic to this problem. As the other answers suggests, it could be a browser cache configuration, or may be that you must build your project after made your changes (check if your Build Automatically option in eclipse is off) and restart your Tomcat to see the changes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's really too bad there isn't a downvote option on comments...

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure your XHTML file is not being cached by your browser. Try a forced refresh (on Firefox, press Shift+Refresh Button or Command+Refresh on Mac).

You might also try to configure Tomcat context to disable caching for static resources as documented in the [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html). Set the cachingAllowed property to false (default is true).

Check HTTP headers using Firebug. See what you is in the HTTP response: HTTP response code, Cache-Control and Expires headers.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sam said, make sure that your files are not being cached by your browser.  On Mac (Command + R) Firefox and Chrome (Shift + F5).

If this does not work, double click the server on Eclipse and go to the **Publishing** tab. Make sure that it is set to **Automatically publish when resources change**.

Comment: You cannot rely on answer ordering.  You can put a link to the answer you refer to.

Comment: How do you add a link to an answer?

Comment: There is a "share" link below each answer.  You may need a certain amount of reputation to see it.